# Parse WinAPI function arguments and return type

Tags: c++, parsing, command-line, header-files

Is there any command-line tool or a python script to parse windows header files (WinAPI functions) and print out it's return type and arguments? Maybe some MSVS command-line tool?

Something like:

```
cmd> api-info psapi.h GetModuleFileNameExW
```

api-info output:

```
return:
DWORD WINAPI
arguments:
__in      HANDLE hProcess
__in_opt  HMODULE hModule
__out     LPWSTR lpFilename
__in      DWORD nSize
```

I know there are complex solutions like clang, but that would be an overkill for this simple functionality which I need.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? [There's already a site dedicated to documenting the Windows API functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447209.aspx). For example, the function signature for [`GetModuleFileNameEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198.aspx) is already provided there.

Comment: I need to write wrapper macros for about 500 winapi functions and I am lazy to do it manually from MSDN site.

Comment: Okay, so what problem are you really trying to solve by writing 500 wrapper macros? I'm almost certain there is a better solution than writing 500 macros.

Comment: I have a piece of assemly code where I redirect all WinAPI functions to hide system calls from disassemblers. However I need to know return value of each system call because return values are stored in different registers for different return types (integers in EAX, floating point values in ST0 x87, etc.).